# Open a window browser from a vaadin table

Tags: action, vaadin, handler

I'm developìng an app in Vaadin and I've found a problem.
I would like to open a new browser window from the action handler added to a vaadin table, and I don't know how to do that. Is that possible?.

```
table.addActionHandler(new Handler() {

    public void handleAction(Action action, Object sender, Object target) {
        if (action == ACTION_OPEN_WINDOW) {
            // code to open a new browser window
            BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener....
            /// is it possible open oit here?               
        }
    }

    public Action[] getActions(Object target, Object sender) {
        return ACTIONS;
    }

});
```

Comment: BrowserWindowOpener requires a component to be clicked on, so I don't think it is possible to use it this way. You'll probably have to use javascript like dmitry suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you still can run JavaScript:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("window.open('http://google.com', 'Google', 'height=800,width=600');");
```